# Position Div over top right corner of input box

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm dynamically inserting DIV on a page, here is simplified example:

http://jsfiddle.net/GEgEc/4/

HTML:

```
<div class="left-column">
    <p>
        <label>Company Name:</label>
        <input type="text" maxlength="255" id="BodyContentPlaceholder_LeftColumnContentPlaceHolder_CompanyNameTextBox" />

    </p>
    <p>
        <label>Phone:</label>
        <input type="text" maxlength="255" id="BodyContentPlaceholder_LeftColumnContentPlaceHolder_PhoneNumberTextBox" __id="105" />         
    </p>
</div>
<div class="right-column">
    <p>
        <label __id="109">Contact Name:</label>
        <input  type="text" maxlength="255" id="BodyContentPlaceholder_LeftColumnContentPlaceHolder_ContactNameTextBox" __id="110" /> 
    </p>
    <p>
        <label>Email:</label>
        <input type="text" maxlength="255" id="BodyContentPlaceholder_LeftColumnContentPlaceHolder_EmailTextBox"  />     </p>
</div>
<div style="clear:both;">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit Request" id="myButton" />
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.inputError {
    border: 1px solid #006;
    background: pink;
}
.divError {
    border: 1px solid black;
    background: red;

}
label {
    float:left;
    width:120px;
    text-align:right;
    margin-right:5px;
}
input[type="text"] {
    width: 150px;
}
.left-column, .right-column {
    float:left;
    position: relative;
}
.left-column p, .right-column p {
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}
.left-column {
    margin-right:5px;
}
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#myButton").on("click", DoTrick);
});

function DoTrick()
{
    var $input = $("#BodyContentPlaceholder_LeftColumnContentPlaceHolder_CompanyNameTextBox");

    var $div = $("<div/>")
        .attr("id", "GGG")
        .addClass("divError")
        .text("This field has error");

    $div.insertAfter($input);

}
```

But ideally I'd like it work in general whenever I *know* input element I want to add DIV that shows on top right of it, this is validation message that should "float"

Right now when I add DIV it breaks layout and doesn't go where I need it.

Comment: Is this not [your other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15603234/asp-net-validation-override-positioning-popup-messages)?

Comment: Yes, I thought I need to simplify

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may be a case for position: absolute.

see http://jsfiddle.net/HNQMm/3/

add a class to wrap the fields (i used .relative) and set it to 'position: relative'.

and then your error box can look like this:

```
.divError {
border: 1px solid black;
background: red;
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 50px;
```

}

.divError's top and left values are now relative to the outer, relative div so you can set them precisely where you need them.

Answer (score 0):

You just position whatever element by pixels. I think it should be something like that:

```
p.pos_fixed
{
position:fixed;
top:30px;
right:5px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

your.divError is a `<div>`, which means it has display:block attribute, so it will sit on a new line.

If you made it a `<span>` instead it will sit inline with the input element (or modify the CSS class)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if i understood you correctly but are you looking for something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/5ZM25/1/

The `insertAfter` could be changed to `insertBefore` and then position it where you want it to be if you want it "over the top right corner of input box".